# Posting information input to form to another page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, post

I am working with wordpress and I want to figure out a way to have a form on one page, and then have the information post to a separate page on the site. I only know html so I don't know how to work through the php at all nor do I know where to put the code to do this. 
I already have a generic form set up, I just can't connect the dots with this and figure out how to display the information back.
I have looked through a dozen or so similar posts, but all of the answers would require that I know more about php. Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: It's good day to start learn php.

Comment: @sectus Yesssserrrrrrryyyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use PHP's `$_POST` to get the values submitted by the form. Set the `action` attribute of your form to the php page.

If this is your form:

```
<form action="second-page.php" method="post">
<input name="field_01">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You access the value of `field_01` in the php like this:

```
$_POST["field_01"];
```

Where `field_01` can be the name of any relevant field that was in the form.

To simplify things, collect all the fields in variables at the top, and `echo` them when you want to put them in your html:

```
<?php
$field_01 = $_POST["field_01"];
?>

<!-- your html -->
<p><?php echo $field_01; ?></p>
```

You can do this for as many fields as you have.

Comment: @Trolleymusic Hi, very cool solution. I am looking for something similar but what I pretend to do is to parse the input from one form to another form (input  field) in a different page . Can you please help me with that . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the action attribute in your form to send the inputted data and $_POST to recieve it. You should be able to look up and learn these two things in a few minutes.

Comment: I will do this! Thank you Snitty!